# Bijectivity involing a set that includes subsets of the domain and codomain

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

Is the function $\theta : \mathscr P(\Bbb Z)\rightarrow \mathscr P(\Bbb Z)$ defined as $\theta (X) = (\bar X)$ bijective? If so, what is its inverse.

So I don't really understand this question. Is  X an element or is it a subset. My intuition tells me that it is a subset of the powerset of the integers. If so then should the expression $\theta (X)$ mean the image of X on $\theta$ or can I actually solve this problem without the use of images? I ask this because this question shows up in my textbook before the section on images and preimages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathscr{P}(\Bbb Z)$ is the power set of the set of integers so it's ``elements'' are subsets of $\Bbb Z$. For example, $\{1,2,3\} \subseteq \Bbb Z$, therefore $\{1,2,3\} \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb Z)$. Furthermore, $\theta(\{1,2,3\})=\Bbb Z -\{1,2,3\}.$

Bijectivity is easy because for ontoness let $S \in \mathscr{P}(\Bbb Z)$, then we can have $\bar{S}=\Bbb Z-S$ as the input such that $\theta(\bar{S})=\bar{\bar{S}}=S$. Likewise one-one is straightforward.

As far as the inverse function is concerned: We want $g:\mathscr{P}(\Bbb Z) \longrightarrow \mathscr{P}(\Bbb Z)$ such that $g(\theta(X))=X=\theta(g(X))$. It should be fairly obvious by now that $g(Y)=\bar{Y}$, i.e. $\theta$ is self-invertible.